# Sikuli GUI Automation - continuous check for external errors

Tags: python, automation, sikuli, jython-2.7

I am trying to automate usage testing with SikuliX 2.0.0, to get the best reproduction of the actual user interaction with my software.

I am hoping for any input or advice on dealing with error handling - not within my Sikuli script, but rather in the software it should be testing.
The program will pop up an error window if anything occurs, and maintains its own log file. However, for testing purposes, it would be really nice if:

-If sikuli sees my error window open, it will stop its current actions;
-Save a screenshot;
-Give an error message with information about what steps of the testing occured directly preceeding.

I know how to do all three things - what I am struggling with, is trying to find a way to have sikuli actively "keep watch" for that error pop up. It's not feasible to add an assert between every action, of course; is there a better option than trying to have asserts at the key moments when things are more likely to crash?

Or simply generate a sikuli log file in case of any errors, on the assumption that any crash of the software would of course also lead to an error in the sikuli testing?

Any creative alternatives for error handling would be welcomed.

NOTE
Unfortunately it's not practical to have my external software try to push an error message to sikuli. It all has to be baked into the sikuli script!

Answer (score 2):

The general approach is using the Sikuli Region observer functionality (you can learn about it [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#observing-visual-events-in-a-region)). It is supposed to be non blocking and you just need to register an event handler that will be used as a callback when the pattern will appear in the defined region.

The general usage [is](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.observe):

```
observe([seconds][, background = False | True])
```

where `background` defines whether you want to run the observation in the background (non-blocking) or not.